# iPhone Bluetooth - External Device

Tags: iphone

Can I program my app to connect to a external bluetooth device other than the handset in order to send/receive data?

BR

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do. you have learn about External Accessory framework.This helps you a lot to proceed with your idea. visit the link for the framework class reference http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference.pdf